# Firewall Request for the HERE Geocode API (v6.2)

Tags: here-api, firewall, geocoder

I'm trying to open our firewall to access the HERE GeocodeAPI but need the IP address range & port info. Does anyone know how to get this? Tried the HERE support team who were not able to provide it.

Endpoint - https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.xml

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to provide fixed range of IP Address in a Cloud Environment.
The recommendation is to make whitelist domain like *.api.here.com or *hereapi.com in order to avoid dependency on IPs.
Please take a look at about Whitelist setting.
https://developer.here.com/blog/how-to-whitelist-domain-names